# Why specifically the size of a date on Yom Kippur?

Tags: food, yom-kippur, fast-days

Often times a kezayis or beitza is the amount of food necessary to transgress a food related prohibition. Why is a date specifically the quantity one must eat to be liable on Yom Kippur?

> [Shulchan Aruch (612:1)](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.612.1?lang=bi&with=Commentary&lang2=en) - האוכל ביום הכפורים ככותב' הגסה חייב והוא
>   פחו' מכביצה מעט ושיעור זה שוה לכל אדם בין לננס בין לעוג מלך הבשן - One
>   who eats on Yom Kippur (an amount) like a large date is obligated (for
>   punishment having transgressed the Torah prohibition) and it is little
>   less that egg-size. This measurement is equal to all people where
>   Nanas (who was small) or Og, the King of Bashan (who was a giant).

Comment: I heard that a date size settles the mind.

Comment: @Russell The Gemara says precisely that in Yoma 79a and 80b.

Comment: @Meir Thank you for the source.

Comment: (ננס is from the Greek (νάνος) for dwarf. I don't think there is a historical figure by the name.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The mishna b'rura this seif points this out:

> (א) ככותבת הגסה - אע"ג דבכל איסורי התורה משערינן בכזית, כל זה הכי דכתיבי אכילה משא"כ ביו"כ דלא כתיב אכילה אלא מנע הכתוב את האכילה בלשון עינוי כדכתיב "הנפש אשר לא תעונה" וקים להו לחכמים דבפחות מככותבת לא מייתבא דעתיה כלל והרי הוא רעב ומעונה כבתחילה
>
> (A) Like a large date - although all prohibitions in the Torah are measured with a *kezayit* (like an egg), this is only where it writes 'eating', unlike Yom Kippur, where it doesn't write 'eating' rather it writes 'denial' as it states "the person who does not practice self denial" and the Sages understood that less than a large date, one's mind is not settled at all, and he is aa hungry and denied as before.

[This, as was mentioned in the comments, is a gemara in Yoma (79a and 80b).]